# Calling New Thread on Method is a Bad idea?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a project that shows, reads(using speech) and mails notifications for the user.

Everything is working, but i have one question that I cant find the answer.

Every time I need to call the speaker class i need to create a new thread. Actually, I'm using a lot of threading to do background work and update some infos.

My doubt:

calling a new thread like this:

```
public void relatmailth()
{
    MAILRELAT mails = new MAILRELAT();
    relatmail = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mails.mail));
    relatmail.IsBackground = true; 
    relatmail.Start();
}
```

every time I need to send a email, is a bad practice?

The Program will manage threads automatically?

I need to "kill"(I know it's not recommended) old threads before calling the new one?

if it is, how I can fix that?

Comment: Why do you need a new thread for an email?

Comment: @Breno Almeida use `Task` instead of manually creating `Thread`

Comment: it was an example... i need a new thread for make use of  SpeechSynthesizer.

it will hang the main thread if executed without a new thread.

Comment: @Node.JS Please, can you Elucidate more?

Comment: @BrenoAlmeida `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Foo())`. By using a `Task` you don't have to manage a `ThreadPool`

Comment: @Node.JS Thanks node! i Will research more, but thanks to point out the use of "Tasks".

Comment: @BrenoAlmeida Good luck. After reading about `Task` try to understand the `async/await` syntax as well so you would be able to wait until the async code (i.e. `Task`) is finished before doing something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's a bad idea since you are creating a thread every time you are calling the send email method. Rather either make it a `async` one like

```
public async Task relatmailth()
{
    MAILRELAT mails = new MAILRELAT();
    // rest of mail sending logic
}
```

Else if you really have to have this method schedule on a separate thread, then use one from ThreadPool using `QueueUserWorkItem()` like

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(relatmailth, "TP Thread");
```

Comment: Thanks! I will research more about the issue and threading. Unfortunatly, my school is not that good and lacks info, most of the time i have to do some search by myself.

Answer (score 8):

> Everything is working

... by accident, probably.

> Every time I need to call the speaker class i need to create a new thread. Actually, I'm using a lot of threading to do background work and update some infos.

That is a very bad practice. Think of threads as workers. If you would not hire a worker to do a task, do not hire a thread to do a task.

> every time I need to send a email, is a bad practice?

Would you hire a new admin assistant every time you wanted to send a letter, and then fire them?

Yes, it is a bad practice.

> I need to "kill"(I know it's not recommended) old threads before calling the new one?

Why are you asking a question when you know the answer? **Never kill a thread**. It is incredibly dangerous.  If you hire a new admin assistant every time you have a letter to put in the mail, do you shoot them when the mail goes in the mailbox?

The CLR guarantees that *its* invariants are maintained when you abort a thread. **The CLR does not guarantee that your program invariants are maintained when you abort a thread**. If you are aborting a thread, you should be aborting *every* thread and shutting down the process in an emergency because you are worried that running threads will corrupt user data. A fail-fast is the safest way to shut down in this emergency situation.

If you are not in an emergency shutdown situation, do not kill threads.

> if it is, how I can fix that?

- All I/O tasks -- sending emails, connecting to databases, reading and writing files, connecting to the network, and so on -- should be done with single-threaded asynchrony.
- All CPU-bound tasks should be either farmed out to a separate process, or assigned a worker thread using the appropriate high-level task scheduling technology, such as the TPL.  **Do not manage your own threads**.  Let the TPL manage your threads, and *only assign it CPU-bound tasks.*

Comment: I'm  aware of how a thread works on theory, but i didn't know how to manage it in practice. I'm on early Computer Science School, i think it is normal to have such questions... it's .not very friendly of you saying that "by accident, probably". but hey! this is the internet, who cares, right?




At least i learned something with your post, thanks anyway.

Comment: @BrenoAlmeida: If you are using threads willy-nilly any time you get stuck, your code almost certainly works only by accident. **Programming correctly with arbitrary threads is extremely difficult because normal rules about programming do not apply**.  The sooner you internalize that fact, the more successful you will be. *You do not know enough about threading to do it correctly, and your code is almost certainly wrong*. That is excellent advice and you would do well to heed it.

Comment: Re, "...If you would not hire a worker to do a task,..." I think that analogy deserves to be fleshed out:  You _could_ say that continually creating new threads for new tasks and then allowing them to die when the tasks are complete is like laying off your employees every time they complete a task, and then re-hiring them each time you've got something new for them to do:  It adds a lot of overhead to each task. Whereas, using a thread pool is like having a room full of workers, some maybe sitting idle, who are ready to start a task on a moment's notice.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: That is a good analogy. Particularly since you are still paying those idle workers! Threads in the CLR take up lots of virtual memory even when they are idle because the CLR commits the entire stack. Now, things get a little more complicated when you add CPUs to the mix. Think of a worker-plus-CPU as being like a driver plus a car. If you have more drivers than cars, some of the drivers are idle even if they have deliveries to make. If you have more cars than drivers, then there are cars that could be in use that are not.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: And if some of those drivers are instead tasked with IO tasks, they are driving their car to a mailbox and then waiting for the letter carrier to arrive, which is a waste of their time. What you really want is *exactly as many threads as there are CPUs*, and all of them doing CPU-bound work. That's why you want to use the TPL; its job is to figure out how to assign threads to CPUs so that you get maximum performance for minimum resource cost.

Comment: @Eric Lippert  i'm not stating that i know enought, what i meant was that i know the basics on what are threads and what they do. Good advoce tho. Now i get what you mean "by accident".